# Eiffel: ODBC Dealing with BIGINT

Tags: odbc, eiffel

### Eiffel

Seems I'm getting an INTEGER_32_REF from a BIGINT from ODBC with Eiffel DB_SELECTION.cursor. Sometimes I seem to have the adecuate value, but sometimes not...

```
946383958 => good INTEGER_32_REF (id->4 of following table)
9475984837 => 886050245 WRONG INTEGER_32_REF (id->4 of following table)

646383958 => good INTEGER_32_REF (id->3 of following table)
6475984837 => -2113949755 WRONG INTEGER_32_REF (id->4 of following table)

...
```

It seems to behave like not treating the BIGINT and giving the INTEGER_32_REF value directly interpreted from the DB value, typical case passing over the 2^32

### Postgresql

Having a table with following data as `electricity_amount BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

```
id |   a_date   |  amount   | electricity_amount | consumption_sector_id | electricity_rate_id
----+------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------
1 | 2019-01-01 | 746383958 |         7475984837 |                     1 |                   1
2 | 2019-02-01 | 846383958 |         8475984837 |                     1 |                   1
3 | 2019-03-01 | 646383958 |         6475984837 |                     1 |                   1
4 | 2019-04-01 | 946383958 |         9475984837 |                     1 |                   1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, not all the data types are mapped to Eiffel side.
So you will need to inherit from the class `GLOBAL_SETTINGS` and call the feature
`set_use_extended_types (True) --| Use extended types: INTEGER_64, STRING_32 etc.`

Comment: solved my problem thx, received an INTEGER_64_REF and with `to_natural_64`